# Convert a multi-line string into a javascript object

Tags: javascript, regex

I've my raw data that looks like this:

```
Last Name, First Name (Details-Details)      #ID
Last Name, First Name (Details-Details)      #ID
Last Name, First Name (Details-Details)      #ID
Last Name, First Name (Details-Details)      #ID
Last Name, First Name (Details-Details)      #ID
Last Name, First Name (Details-Details)      #ID
x1000
```

I'd like to convert into a loopable object with keys and values something like:

```
var d = {
    "FirstName LastName": "#ID";
    "FirstName LastName": "#ID";
    "FirstName LastName": "#ID";
    "FirstName LastName": "#ID";
    "FirstName LastName": "#ID";
    "FirstName LastName": "#ID";
};
```

How can convert this to a javascript object? I'm thinking `stringify` may be a good starting point. `FirstName` have different values. They are just for the purpose of demonstration

Comment: Use regex to extract data

Comment: maybe use regex to extract data and convert it to object like you want.

Comment: yea it's not JSON. above is it's format when pasted in too notepad

Comment: Please post the actual data. You cannot have duplicate keys in an object. Are `First Name` etc just placeholders?

Comment: I mean all the names and ID's are different. above is for the purpose of demonstration

Comment: @EthanPrisonMike please use better sample data in your question, something that actually makes sense as a JS object. What is `(Details-Details)`? Is it literally that or something else?

Comment: #ID - number or string ?

Comment: neither of the datapoints I'm targeting are in string format. ID's are always in the format of a letter followed by 6 numbers like --> J778642. No problem with them being stored as strings either I need to edit that

Comment: (details-details) is just other information that's not needed. I really just need to be able to loop through the object to extract an ID to push into an API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string at `\n`
- loop through each line using `map`
- Use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with the regex `/(.*), (.*) \(.*\)\s+(.*)/` to get first name, last name into capturing groups (**[demo](https://regex101.com/r/VWklCp/1)**)
- create an object from the array using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let str =
`LastName1, FirstName1 (Details-Details)      #ID1
LastName2, FirstName2 (Details-Details)      #ID2
LastName3, FirstName3 (Details-Details)      #ID3`

let output = str.split("\n")
                .map(a => a.match(/(.*), (.*) \(.*\)\s+(.*)/))
                .reduce((r, [, last, first, id]) => {
                    r[`${first} ${last}`] = id
                    return r;
                },{})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: gonna give this a shot. some last names have commas so I'll have to edit out and reapply after conversion. I'll lyk

Comment: @EthanPrisonMike it doesn't matter if the last names have `,` https://regex101.com/r/rf7x7B/1

Comment: @EthanPrisonMike that doesn't affect the regex as well. Try it on regex101

Comment: I'm using vs code. threw the apostrophe at the beginning of the object and end like you did and it's erroring out after the first line. error at the end of the first line is ("unterminated string literal") essentially the 2500 lines won't convert into a giant string. I should probably mention I'm trying to do all this in a js file as well

Comment: @EthanPrisonMike that's not an apostrophe, that's a backtick. The string is called a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It allows us to create [multi-line strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Multi-line_strings) without adding `+ "\n"` everywhere

Comment: wow. i've been teaching myself this stuff and cannot tell you how much time knowing about a backtick would have saved me lol I'm using the google web console to convert it and it's loosing the key as a string and the ending comma. any suggestions on another spot to run it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by  *"it's loosing the key"*. The code I've posted is runnable. Click on "Run code snippet". You can also test it on sites like jsfiddel: https://jsfiddle.net/pydv2x4r/

Comment: The code you posted runs great inside of the page but when it's run on fiddle the console of the web browser drops the ending comma and stringification(?) of the first value. so what is returned is ------> FirstName LastName: "#ID" instead of "FirstName LastName": "#ID",

Comment: @EthanPrisonMike that's just how the browser's console displays object literals. If you try `console.log(JSON.stringify(output))`, you'll see the object in a JSON format with quotes around keys and comma after each property. (TBH, I've never noticed that object literals don't show comma in the browser's console)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract the data, use [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method to extract data using a regular expression.

```js
var str = `Last Name1, First Name1 (Details-Details)      j1
Last Name2, First Name2 (Details-Details)      32
Last Name3, First Name3 (Details-Details)      3
Last Nam4e, First Name4 (Details-Details)      4
Last Name5, First Name5 (Details-Details)      5
Last Name6, First Name6 (Details-Details)     6`


// pattern for matching the string
let reg = /([\w ]+)\b\s?,\s?([\w ]+)\b\s*\([^)]+\)\s*([\w\d]+)/g;

// variable for storing match
let m;

// object for the result
let res = {};

// iterate over the matches
while (m = reg.exec(str)) {
// define object property based on the match
  res[`${m[2]} ${m[1]}`] = m[3];
}

console.log(res);
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/8yNBxL/2)