# Convert a local text file into object in javascript as user configuration file

Tags: javascript, regex, javascript-objects

I was trying to make a 'save file' so users can download and load their config into the site.
here's what I'm trying to accomplish:
config.txt

```
projectName: 'Lorem',
timeStarted: '12:21:00',
tasks: [
'Do this',
'Do that',
'Then this',
'Then that'
]
```

js object

```
projectName: 'Lorem',
timeStarted: '12:21:00',
tasks: [
'Do this',
'Do that',
'Then this',
'Then that'
]
```

I've tried the method from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293472/convert-a-multi-line-string-into-a-javascript-object#) using split, map, and reduce but still failing to convert the text into the object

here's my code:

```
let str = [config.txt];
let output = str.split("\n")
                        .map(a => a.match(/(.*): '(.*)',/))
                        .reduce([haven't figured out this part]);
```

I want the object to have an array inside.

Comment: Why don't you just use [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) instead? And the data structure in your question is invalid by the way.

Comment: The js object you posted is not valid; it looks like `tasks` property should be an array and not an object

Comment: @Dario @str my bad, yes I wanted the `tasks` to be an array. How can I actually use the JSON to make object with an array inside?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution by using JSON as follows

```
//to set the object
var config = {
    "projectName": "Lorem",
    "timeStarted": "12:21:00",
    "tasks": [
    "Do this",
    "Do that",
    "Then this",
    "Then that" ]
}

// to convert the object into string
var asString = JSON.stringify(config);

// to process and parse the string back to object
var asObject = JSON.parse(asString);
```

I wasn't able to use `JSON.parse()` before because I put the `config` object as the parameter.